# iconmonstr icon support in react native

Tags: react-native, icons

I want to show icon from class name in react native for ex :- im im-icon-Car-3 , im im-icon-Home...
I have tried to search which type of icons they are this is what i have found .
https://iconmonstr.com/iconicfont/
I have font file but how can i show icons from class name i am not getting.
I have tried to show icons using below mentioned lib but didn't succeed
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vector-icons

can anyone suggest any lib for icons to show from class name as given examples of classname

Answer (score 0):

let's tried install step by step `react-native-vector-icons`, because it's work fine.
example :

```
import Feather from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  return (
     <Feather name="chevron-left" color={'#2F80ED'} size={30} />
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response .. class names which i have mentioned are working in your code ? because there are many   categories like fontawesome , material icons , iocnic , feather but i want to get icons from class names which i mentioned